# Users asking to reset password in account registration

Tags: user-behavior, login, registration, signup-signon

Ive been pouring through responses in a customer satisfaction survey we put in our account registration and I've noticed a few responses that surprise me. Several people have gone to account registration (clicked "Create a Free Account" on the home page), then explain in their survey response that they wanted to reset their password.

This capability is obviously available on the Sign In/Login screen, but its very atypical for that to be in registration. Any thoughts as to why that might be?

Comment: There could be a number of variables here. Some off the top of my head: Are your links easily distinguishable, or do they look like they could be related to the same action? Are your links too small/close together? Is the create account page clear as to what it's purpose is? Some registration forms offer a section that states "Already have an account? Sign in! Or, get help signing in." Have you tested a design like that to see if it alleviates some of these concerns? Lastly, if this is a very small percentage of responses, I might just monitor it to see if others run into the same issue.

Comment: This is really hard to answer without more context. Could you provide the screenshot or some rough mockup?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps consider asking to virtually meet with the users that mentioned they experienced this problem and have them share their screen and show you what is happening.